# Algorithm for enumerating grid points by distance from given point

Tags: combinatorics, euclidean-geometry

I'm trying to devise an algorithm for enumerating all points on a 2D grid in order of their Euclidean distance to a given target point.  I know I could just get a bunch of them that are close to the target and then sort them, but that's not what I want.  I want something that will output every point, out to infinity, in order of their distance to the target.

At the bare minimum, I need something that works if the target point is also a grid point.  But ideally, I want something that works for any target, even non-grid points.  Ideally ideally, I want something that works for grids of an uneven x-y scale.

Any ideas on where to start with this?

Comment: Start as you suggested; take a number of lattice point close to the origin, sort them by distance from the origin, and look for a pattern.  For example, sort $\{(x,y)|-10\leq x,y\leq 10\}$ in increasing order of $x^2+y^2$ and see what you get.

Comment: Are your out-of-grid points rational (combinations of grid points)? Or some sort of algebraic ones? Or the most complex case of transcendental ones is the one?

Comment: Yes, out-of-grid points can be assumed rational

Comment: Then your way is towards integer quadratic forms. Whatever the actual problem(s) you face...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for the corners of the square your target is in, every grid point has a neighbor that is closer to the target. So you can use a modified breadth-first search:

Maintain a **priority queue** of points that you have not printed yet but are neighbors to something you *have* printed, ordered by (squared) distance to the target. Keep taking out the closest point and adding those of its remoter neighbors that are not already in the queue.

This uses $O(\sqrt n)$ space to print $n$ points, and it takes $O(\log n)$ work to print point number $n$.

Comment: I was really hoping for something that works in O(1) time, but I think this should suffice....